report progress with IProgressinterface and progress.Report in MVVM
I am having some issues to correctly report the progress of my async tasks. I made this class
using PropertyChanged;
using System;

[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class SyncProgress
{
    public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Percentage { get; set; } = 0;
}

i have this long running Task in my view model which is a sequence of multiple methods:
private async Task StartSync(CancellationToken token, IProgress<SyncProgress> progress)
{
    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("started.");
        //get folders paths from database (_fileMetadataManager is acting as a model)
        var folderPaths = await Task.Run(() => 
        _fileMetadataManager.GetFolderPathsAsync(token, progress));
        //get all filesInfo objects in the folders
        var fileList = await Task.Run(() => 
        _fileMetadataManager.ScanFolderAsync(folderPaths, token, progress));
    }
}

I am a very confused on how to utilize the same progress object along the whole chain of tasks and report relevant updates.
my Ui is binded to a public proprierty that i delclare in the View model
public SyncProgress Progress { get; set; }

class constructor()
{
  Progress = new SyncProgress();
}


<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Progress.Message}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

I am also lost on how to report the progress from the child methods. I passed the object but should I create a new instance of the SyncProgress object from the child methods? it seems quite a waste of memory
ChildMethod(token, progress)
{
  progress.Report(new SyncProgress("test", 10);
}


IProgress<T> is intended to be used with immutable types for T (to avoid all kinds of bugs that happen when data used by 2 or more threads changes unexpectedly), so change your SyncProgress class to have only { get; }-only properties and add a constructor.

Furthermore, IProgress<T> types aren't intended to be used with databinding because they're immutable.

Your StartSync method is already async - it doesn't need await Task.Run - just await the methods directly (and should not have the suffix Sync)

I think you're too rightly coupled: you should (concurrent) queue your messages, and let another thread / worker handle the reporting.

The Sync suffix only seems to indicate what kind of work the method is doing, i.e. synchronize something. Besides that, it is unclear in which way the GetFolderPathsAsync and ScanFolderAsync method would get a notion of the total amount of work that has to be done. How would you calculate a percentage of work done otherwise?

As IProgress only seems to used internally in the view model, there is also no need to have an IProgress<SyncProgress> argument to the StartSync method. The view model would instead have a private member of type Progress<SyncProgress> that is passed to the GetFolderPathsAsync and ScanFolderAsync methods. That Progress instance could update the public SyncProgress Progress property in handler that is attached to its ProgressChanged event.
